# Where are the windows api files located?

Tags: winapi, assembly, linker, nasm

I'm currently persuing to create a compiler. Because of that I am learning nasm x86 assembly.
I never really coded in c++ or c so I never really used the winapi. When I used ld I could successfully link and create a 32 bit executable but it doesn't use "the real winapi" since it uses a libkernel32.a file internally.
Now, I know this might sound like a silly question but where are files like kernel32.dll located on a default installation of windows 10 64 bit? Maybe the one in the C:\Windows\System32 folder but these somehow won't work with neither ld nor golink.

Comment: Each of the Windows system DLLs has a corresponding *export library* that should be used for linking. Thus, for "kernel32.dll" there will be, somewhere in the development environment or SDK, a "kernel32.lib" file, which will be used by the linker.

Comment: *"it doesn't use "the real winapi" since it uses a libkernel32.a file internally"* - libkernel32.a is an *import library*. It doesn't contain any code, not even function stubs. It merely contains symbols and information on the module that exports it. The linker uses this import library to generate the import table of the final executable image. Not every OS implements linking the same way Linux does.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. @IInspectable I'm a little confused right now. I thought kernel32.dll is a system file and that the linkers are using it to link with your code but what I got out of your comment is that linkers are more like an interface to use e.g. the winapi. I'm just really confused could you maybe elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Linkers *doesn't* use *dynamic link libraries* to link your program against *dynamic link libraries*. As @IInspectable stated, they use the import libraries.

Comment: libkernel32.a (or kernel32.lib) are import libraries. The linker uses them to resolve imports, and places an import table into the [PE image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). On process creation, the OS loader uses the import table to resolve imports. Each referenced module (such as kernel32.dll) is loaded, the imported functions are looked up, and a table is built from the addresses of the imported symbols. The compiler/linker-generated code accesses imports through this table. The linker is not involved in process creation; all required information is in the PE image.

Comment: The OS loader honors the [dynamic-link library search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) when resolving imports.

Comment: Massive thank to all of you that helped me :).